# Can the links to duplicate questions be made more obvious?

Tags: feature-request

When a question is closed as a duplicate:

- Links to the duplicate questions are placed at the top
- A close message is placed at the bottom

On several occasions I have seen responses to duplicate questions such as:

> [is there any duplicate available then plz send me the url I will remove my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667525/how-to-change-url-after-every-ajax-call-in-php?noredirect=1#comment60927050_36667525)

Could the duplicate links be made more obvious?

Perhaps by changing the close message from:

> This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question.

to

> This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question (linked from the top of this page).

Comment: It might be useful to have the duplicate linked at the bottom as well

Comment: Spread that dupe link allover the post. Put it above, put it in the close banner, put it in the title and random in between the questions body. People are stupid, people can't read, people don't bother reading even if they're capable to do so. We cannot improve SO unless we find a good method to improve _people_.

Comment: I'm tightly working in a team with Sheldon Cooper now, to find a solution how to improve people. We're struggling still with some basic definitions to agree regarding _improvement_.