# When we mention a question from Main on a Meta post, can we have an automatic link?

Tags: feature-request, questions, meta

Practically every time I write a post on Meta which mentions a question from Main, it is relevant for people reading the question on Main to know about the Meta post. Sometimes it is useful information which clarifies policy, sometimes it is even more closely coupled. For example, I made a Meta question today which was a specific discussion about whether a given question from Main is on topic. I had to take special care to link to the Meta question so people will know there is discussion about it, but it is possibly being lost in the list of comments.

I propose a feature: when somebody writes a Meta question and includes an existing question from Main in its body (or title, I suppose - don't know if this is possible) the question from Main should get either a comment or a post notice saying something on the lines of "this question is part of a Meta discussion", with a link to the discussion.

This will reduce the users' effort of setting these links manually, eliminate the risk of them forgetting to set them at all, and, if the notice variant is chosen, people will realize that there is a discussion they can take into account before writing comments or voting to close.

I am sure that this idea can use some thought in fleshing out. For example, it would be probably not so useful if applied to [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) questions, so it could be automatically restricted to link [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) questions. (Idea suggested by rene in comments).

Comment: Not all meta discussions warrant a comment and I doubt anyone is going to clean-up those comments once the debate has been settled. So that is a no from me for this feature. We can do it by hand when needed.

Comment: @rene I cannot remember an example where a Meta discussion mentioning a question does not warrant a comment at the question itself, and I am not sure why you will want to have it cleaned up - people tend to come up with the same ideas over and over, so it is better to know that something has been discussed already. Do you have examples of where a discussion exists, but a comment is not warranted?

Comment: Here you go: [321168](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321168),  
[321172](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321172),  
[321195](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321195),  
[326611](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326611),  
[326640](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326640),  
[284939](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284939),  
[284987](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284987),  
[265522](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265522),  
[265544](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265544),  
[265556](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265556)

Comment: and I think I have [1565](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/673454) other examples ...

Comment: @rene if the information is there to see for a machine - "feature only needed on discussion questions and superfluous on feature request or bug questions" - then this is no problem, we can still have an automated feature but make it go by tag.

Comment: sure, you might want to update your question in that case.

Comment: This will never work, as people never link to the right things.  They'll ask a question about an answer and link to the question.  Or about a question, and link to a comment.  Or about a comment, and link to the google cached version.  It's the bane of my existence.  I've punched so many babies because of it.